# Target of URI doesn't exist error in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In the file test, there is an error:

> Target of URI doesn't exist  : ' package: Flutter/material.dart'

Comment: 'F' should be lowercase -  package:flutter/material.dart

Answer (score 2):

'F' should be lowercase as: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` and you should not include any `spaces` in your imports statements. There is a space before `Flutter`.